# Why use timing belt drives in Stepper Driven Robotic Arm

Tags: robotic-arm, motor, stepper-motor

This may be a noob question. I am sorry if it is but I am new to this field. I am working on a design of SCARA Robot and I am using Stepper Motors to drive it. In many youtube videos, I have seen that they increase the torque using timing belts. Now I understand that in most cases timing belts are used for keeping motors away from the joints to reduce inertia. But I don't understand why they use ratio in belt drive. As far as I know, Stepper motors provide high torque at low speeds and vice versa. Then Stepper Motor should provide that much torque at reduced speed by default, right? Or I am missing something?

Comment: `they increase the torque` ... you answered your own question

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I think they would provide more torque at low speeds by themselves instead of using a belt drive and then turning the Stepper motor at high speeds (thus producing low torque) and then increasing it using a timing belt. Why would they use a timing belt to do something that the motor itself can do? or is it that the torque that they want is outside the stepper motor's torque-speed characteristics? and can not achieve by reduced speed of stepper motor?

Comment: those are good questions ... you could ask the `they` ... or you could analyze a design

Comment: You are right. I should have asked them first. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even at zero speed, stepper motors have a max torque, called the holding torque. If your design needs even higher torque than that, you *could* use a bigger (heavier, more expensive) motor. Alternatively, use a ratio in the belt drive.

To be concrete: a 1:2 ratio will double the available torque, but at the expense of making things 2x slower. It will also double the resolution by making each stepper step half-size.

A design with a very high ratio would start looking like a gearbox, which would suggest revisiting the approach.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Increasing the resolution makes much sense. I think that might be the reason. Commonly they move 1.8 degrees and that would make big difference in the final end-effector position if it is attached to a 500mm long arm.

Comment: If the answer worked for you, a green check mark would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As r-bryan answered they do increase the effective torque. However that also increases the effective resolution giving you better repeatability. As an example a direct drive motor that provided a 0.1 degree repeatability using a 4 to 1 ratio belt drive would give you a 0.025 degree resolution. The trade off is a lower speed.

As secondary effect is that in case of a collision, the belt will absorb a certain amount of the impact possibly preventing damage to the motor.